# What's wrong with javascript code

Tags: javascript

When you run this code in the console, it works fine but not working this way - http://jsbin.com/raguquka/1/

This works on console -

```
function solveEquation() {
    // format ax+by=c
    var eq1 = "3x+5y=4", // equation 1
        eq2 = "5x+6y=2", // equation 2

        // separate ax, by & c
        eq1Parts = eq1.split(/[\+\-\=]/),
        eq2Parts = eq2.split(/[\+\-\=]/),

        // get the value of a, b & c
        a1 = parseInt(eq1Parts[0]),
        b1 = parseInt(eq1Parts[1]),
        c1 = parseInt(eq1Parts[2]),
        a2 = parseInt(eq2Parts[0]),
        b2 = parseInt(eq2Parts[1]),
        c2 = parseInt(eq2Parts[2]),

        // substitution and elimination
        // https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/systems-of-eq-and-ineq/fast-systems-of-equations/e/systems_of_equations

        B1 = b1 * a2,
        C1 = c1 * a2,
        B2 = b2 * a1,
        C2 = c2 * a1,
        // A1 and A2 cancels out, no need to specify them

        // unknowns
        y = (C1 - C2) / (B1 - B2),
        x = (c1 - b1 * y) / a1; // putting the value of y in equation 1

    ansContainer.textContent = "x = " + x + ", y = " + y;
}
```

I know this is a buggy code, it is the very early stage and I stuck.

Comment: ansContainer.textContent is not defined

Comment: `ansContainer = document.getElementById("ans-container")`

Comment: Console tells you everything, look at it for error messages.

Comment: define the expected output, the actual output and the boundary conditions (what values are variables outside the scope of this function that should produce the output). Pointing to a fiddle is nice, but it doesn't suffice.

Comment: there is no error in the console...

Comment: In the console it says `ReferenceError: eq1Container is not defined` when you run the method.

Comment: @epascarello but I've defined that..

Comment: If jsbin adds it to the head, than you are referencing elements before they are rendered to the page.

Comment: @epascarello you'd like to check out this - http://ge.tt/3BJ6HOK1/v/0?c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a divide by zero.

```
var eq1Container = document.getElementById("input-eq1"),
    eq2Container = document.getElementById("input-eq1"), <-- references same input
```

Comment: oh shit.... hahaha I cant believe this.
this is a silly mistake... I had been suck on this for hours but couldn't find that.
thanks.